# PrintDocument with Image VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, printdocument

Is Possible to get Image in pdf where we save pdf from PrintDocument
[image]

Here i added an picturebox , button, printdocument, printpreviewdialog

In printDocument
[image]

Code:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub PrintDocument2_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument2.PrintPage
        Dim XPos, YPos As Long
        XPos = 300
        YPos = 20
        Dim MyFont As New Font("Arial", 18)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Stack Overflow is Best", MyFont, Brushes.Black, XPos + 30, YPos)
        YPos += 50
        YPos += 75
        MyFont = New Font("Arial", 12)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox2.Image, XPos - 200, YPos + 50, 300, 300)
        
    End Sub


    
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        PrintPreviewDialog2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

But while i save that file and open it doesn't contain picture.

[image]

Comment: To start, I'd comment out the DrawImage() line, save another file, and see if the file sizes between the two versions are notably different.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yea i tried one file is 82.7kb with DrawImage(), 81.8kb without DrawImage()

Comment: That tells us something. It's not 0 bytes, so something was drawn, but the image itself is probably much more than the 0.9kb difference between the two files. If I had to guess, I'd bet it drew a blank (all white) image that lent itself well to compression. Perhaps something between the preview and the actual print reset or temporarily cleared the picturebox?

Comment: Maybe it could be the problem but why i dont know the reason its not showing

Comment: I used your code for testing and the picture was printed correctly. Perhaps you can provide some other information so that we can find the problem. Such as your image format, etc.

Comment: @JiachenLi-MSFT I forgot to mention that i retrive the Image from Database

Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
            Picture1.Image.Save(mStream, Picture1.Image.RawFormat)
            ImageBytes = mStream.ToArray()
        End Using
Dim cmd0 As New SqlCommand("Insert into PictureSlide(Picture) values("@photo", Conn)
        With cmd0.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image)
            .Value = ImageBytes
            .Size = ImageBytes.Length
        End With

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save the image locally and then print it.